# Python 3.5 chat server with multiple clients

Tags: python, server, client

Creating a python chat server and create both a server and client the works with only one client. Wondering how i will get it to work with two or more clients. I am using Python 3.5.

Server code:

```
import socket
 
def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000
     
    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.bind((host,port))
     
    mySocket.listen(1)
    conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if not data:
                    break
            print ("from connected  user: " + str(data))
             
            data = str(data).upper()
            print ("sending: " + str(data))
            conn.send(data.encode())
             
    conn.close()
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Client code:

```
import socket

def Main():
    HOST, PORT = '127.0.0.1', 5000

    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.connect((HOST,PORT))

    message = input (" -> ")

    while message != 'q':
        mySocket.send(message.encode())
        data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode()

        print ('Received from server: ' + data)

        message = input(" -> ")

    mySocket.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Deploy your code in any client machine by making the code access to server IP address!

Comment: A nice example for a chat-server with multiple clients can be found [here](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-pysocks/#N10518).